# VS2022 Adding prefix to default namespace for whole solution

Tags: c#, msbuild, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I have a .NET 6 VS2022 c# solution, where each project has a default namespace set as $(MSBuildProjectName.Replace(" ", "_")) - see project -> properties -> DefaultNamespace -> its automatically set by project template. What I would like to do is to have a prefix for namespaces in every project part of this solution.

So, something like this:

```
<RootNamespace>MyCompany.MyProject.$(MSBuildProjectName.Replace(" ", "_"))</RootNamespace>
```

I can do this for each project manually, but what I would like to do is, to have some global variable on solution level, where I could set two vairables:

```
<CompanyName>MyCompany</CompanyName>
<ProjectName>MyProject</ProjectName>
```

Which would result in

$(MyCompany).$(MyProject).$(MSBuildProjectName.Replace(" ", "_"))

This solution should also be compatible with dotnet build procedure and docker-compose, so that it does not break any of them. In a nutshell, with these variables user should still be able to clone git repository on a brand new pc, and build the project without any extra work.

Any ideas? I read that you can create a solution props file where you can define variables, but looks like its a C++ specific?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The project files are MSBuild. You can add custom MSBuild to all your projects with `Directory.Build.props` and `Directory.Build.targets` files.

In the root of your code tree (or a directory in your code tree that contains all of the relevant projects) create a file named `Directory.Build.targets`. Each project when run, searches up the directory hierarchy looking for a file named `Directory.Build.targets`. If such a file is found, it is automatically imported.

Place your properties and property re-definitions in the `Directory.Build.targets` file.

Example:

```xml
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- Custom Properties -->
    <CompanyName>MyCompany</CompanyName>
    <ProjectName>MyProject</ProjectName>
    <!-- Redefine MSBuild Properties -->
    <Company>$(CompanyName)</Company>
    <RootNamespace>$(CompanyName).$(ProjectName).$(MSBuildProjectName.Replace(" ", "_"))</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

A better organization if you are likely to have a lot of customizations would be to place the custom properties in the .props file and the redefinitions in the .targets file.

`Directory.Build.props` and `Directory.Build.targets` were added in MSBuild v15 and are not language specific. In the MSBuild documentation, see [Customize your build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2022).

For the `Company` property see [Assembly attribute properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#assembly-attribute-properties).

Comment: With this solution I have to define the project name for every project I add?

Comment: In the original question `MyProject` is not the name of a project file (or assembly). It is the name of the overall product or application or system that the company is producing. (Two different usages of 'project'.)

Comment: Then this solution could be exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for clarifying :)

Comment: I had to delete the .vs folder and restart Visual Studio for the Directory.Build.targets file to take effect.